# Employee running Facebook Page No longer with company

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

We have a **Facebook page** for our **company** and the only person who had access to it is no longer employed.  We are unable to log in to the page because it is linked to the employee's personal email account.

How can we claim this page on Facebook and gain access?

Answer (score 1):

There are some tips [here](https://www.techprevue.com/how-to-claim-a-facebook-page/).  Otherwise, contact Facebook Support.

It seems **Twitter** is a good way

> Contact Facebook on Twitter
> These days, one of the ways you can contact a company is by tweeting them on Twitter, and Facebook is no exception.
>
> You can send a tweet to one of Facebook’s Twitter handles, and possibly get a response. There’s no guarantee your query will be looked at, but it’s worth trying if your issue doesn’t need to be fixed urgently.
>
> Some of Facebook’s official handles are @Meta, @FacebookApp, and @Messenger.

From [howtogeek](https://www.howtogeek.com/848523/how-to-contact-facebook-for-account-help/)